# Is there a way to keep and update global values in the middle of a sequential scan in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

I am creating a PostgreSQL function in C that compares the minimum ​​of partial sums in an array type column of a table and outputs 3 records in ascending order.

I would like to implement a process that does not calculate the sum after that if the sum of values exceeds the 3rd minimum value up to that point.
Is there such a method?

I have created the following function. If we can keep the 3 minimum values during the sequential scan, we can omit useless calculations when the `tmp` value exceeds the minimum value.

C function:

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(sum_of_5_elements);
Datum
sum_of_5_elements(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  // get input array
  ArrayType *a_ext   = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0);
  Datum *a;
  bool *a_null; 
  Oid a_typid = ARR_ELEMTYPE(a_ext);
  int16 a_typlen; 
  bool a_typbyval;
  char a_typalign;
  int a_len;

  get_typlenbyvalalign(a_typid, &a_typlen, &a_typbyval, &a_typalign);
  deconstruct_array(a_ext, a_typid, a_typlen, a_typbyval, a_typalign, &a, &a_null, &a_len);

  // calculation      
  float sum, tmp;
  for (int i = 0; i < a_len - 5; i++) {
    tmp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      if (!a_null[i + j])
        tmp += a[i + j];
    }
    if (sum > tmp)
      sum = tmp;
  }

  PG_RETURN_DATUM(Float4GetDatum(sum));
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum_of_5_elements (IN array float4[]) RETURN RECORD
   AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME','sum_of_5_elements' LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
SELECT sum_of_5_elements(array_column::float4[]) sum5
   FROM test_table
   ORDER BY sum5 ASC
   LIMIT 3;
```

Sample input:

```
| id |            array_column              |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | array[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] |
|  2 | array[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] |
|  3 | array[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] |
|  4 | array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] |
```

Sample output:

```
| id |            array_column              | sum5(min of sum_of_5_elements) |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|  2 | array[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] |                1               |    
|  1 | array[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] |                3               |    
|  3 | array[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] |                5               |
```

While calculating the record of `id` 4, I want to stop the calculation when `sum` exceeds the 3rd minimum value up to the point (5).

Comment: What is your code, and what have you tried?

Comment: I added the code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The function call context is passed a pointer you can use to allocate memory that is persisted across the scan. I don't remember the exact details, but a look at existing functions should be informative.

Comment: I searched for the corresponding function, but I could not find it. Can you tell me the existing functions or source code references actually using global memory?

Comment: Is there anyone who suggests a detailed method to me?